# VBA delay millisecond timer using API

Tags: vba

I need a VBA millisecond (~100) delay timer and tried using the API:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Then use `Sleep(100)` in a sub.

But, when I try using it I get a compiler error:

```
    "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and
     declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules"
```

I get the same error if I change it to 'Private'.

Any clues as to how I can get this to work?
Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: I can't replicate this if it's declared as `Private Declare ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the error is this (emphasis mine):

> "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and
>        **declare statements not allowed as Public members *of object modules***"

In other words, you apparently can't have a `Public Declare` statement in a class module.

Add a new standard/procedural (.bas) module, and move the `Declare` statement(s) there. Or, make it `Private` if that's the only module it's used in.

Should "just work" ;-)